# The function $f:G \rightarrow G$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ is a homomorphism iff G is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group. The function $f:G \rightarrow G$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ is a homomorphism iff G is abelian.

I am having trouble with the 2nd part of the proof.

Proof:

Assume the function $f:G \rightarrow G$ is defined by $f(x)=x^2$ then:

1. Assume $f$ is a homomorphism then $f$ satisfies the property:
   $$ f(xy)=f(x)f(y) $$

where $x,y \in G$

Notice how:
$$f(xy)=(xy)^2=xyxy$$
$$f(x)f(y)=x^2y^2=xxyy $$

Since $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ then by substitution:

$$xyxy=xxyy$$

Multiplying the right by $y^{-1}$ and the left by $x^{-1}$ then:

$$yx=xy$$ which means G is abelian

2. Assume G is abelian, we want to show $f$ is a homomorphism

For the 2nd part of the proof, would I just work backwards from the first part of the proof? Here is an outline:

then for $x,y \in G$

$$yx=xy$$ by definition of abelian groups.

Multiple the right by y and the left by x, we have:

$$xyxy=xxyy$$

which is equal to:
$$(xy)^2=(x)^2(y)^2$$

since we are given $f(x)=x^2$ then translating this to the above statement:
$$f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$$

which satisfies the property of homomorphism.

Does that look right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is indeed correct and just to put it in a nice way what you can do for the 2nd part is the following

You need to show that $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$. Proceed as follows
\begin{align*}
f(xy) &= (xy)^2\\
&=xyxy\\
&=xxyy & & (\text{because $xy=yx$})\\
&=x^2y^2\\
&=f(x)f(y).
\end{align*}

Comment: that looks nicer!